# Correct for cage effects using pooled control with ordinal response

Tags: ordinal-data, control-group

#### Description of the dataset

I have a data set with three categorical explanatory variable (treatment, environment, "cage") and an ordinal response (very low, low, medium, high,...). To control for "cage" effects each cage contains a pool of controls. Each pool of controls has of course the same environment as the pool of test subjects that are in the same cage, and all controls share the same treatment across cages and environments.

#### Objective of the analysis

I am trying to use the ordinal response of the controls to correct for the cage effect to be able to look at the effect of the explanatory variable of interest: treatment.

#### Previous findings

It looks to me like a fairly standard experimental design but, until now, I only found models that create a continuous response (score) from the ordinal response using an arbitrarily weighted average, or models based on a contingency table where the test subjects with a certain ordinal response can be match to the controls with a given ordinal response.

#### Question

Is there any method that either deals with my type of data where controls and test subjects are pooled within cages and cannot be matched at the individual level, or at least, converts the ordinal data into a score by estimating appropriate weights?

Comment: Description of the setup is a bit unclear. But, it sounds like you have several cages. You have an ordinal DV. From each cage, you randomly assigned some animals (?) to treatment and some to control. Correct? I'm not familiar with R, but this sounds like random effects ordinal logistic/probit. You add a random effect for each cage.

Comment: Yes, you got my setup perfectly. _Random effect ordinal probit_ is exactly what I was looking for, but without the proper name, I could not find the right R-package. For info, before, I mostly found answers mentioning the `lme4` R-package but could not find a way to make it consider ordinal data (no probit regression, ordinal family...), but the packages `ordinal` and  `MCMCglmm` seem to both implement this in different ways. @WeiwenNg: if you re-write your comment as an answer (maybe with a little more detail on the model...), I will accept it!

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two ways of approaching the fact that animals within a cage are likely to be more similar than animals in general.

If you have a small number of cages then you can just add another fixed factor for cages. It will be of very limited scientific interest but it will account for the correlation with cages. You can also add its interaction with your treatment variable to see if the treatment effect varies between cages.

Alternatively as @WeiwenNg suggests in a comment you can fit cage as a random intercept. This would certainly be preferable if there are many cages. Again you could also have a random (slope) effect for treatment if you think the treatment effect may also vary. Providing code advice is strictly speaking off-topic here bu, as you yourself suggest in a comment, the ordinal package has a wide range of facilities (I have never used MCMCglmm).